# How can I organize many environment varaibles within a spring boot project?

Tags: environment-variables

I have a spring boot project that runs on 4 different environments. Each environment uses a different amount of datasources which will be implemented as environment variables through the properties file. How can I organize all these within my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Spring Boot application perspective, a configuration property can be fed from different sources. Such sources inclue environment variables, system properties, command line arguments... etc.

Spring Boot handles the different sources for you. Please look at this page for the details of [Externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

So, if your application expects a configuration property "x.y.z", you may simply define an environment variable "X_Y_Z" (in each of your target environments), and its value will be automatically taken into account in your application.

For the exact syntax of the environment variables to define, you might want to look at the [documentation of relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).